# Spark - union dataframe rows into one row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe that contains rows with identical id.
I need to union all the rows with the same id into one row (one json)

Here is example of the data:

```
id  first_name   last_name
1    JAMES         SMITH
2    MARY          BROWN
2    DAVID         WILLIAMS
1    ROBERT        DAVIS
```

the requested result is:

```
{
  id:1,
  entities: [{
    first_name:JAMES,
    last_name:SMITH 
   }, {
    first_name:ROBERT,
    last_name:DAVIS
  }]
}
{
  id:2,
  entities: [{
    first_name:MARY,
    last_name:BROWN 
   }, {
    first_name:DAVID,
    last_name:WILLIAMS
  }]
}
```

Can it be done?

Regards, Yaniv

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` and `collect_list` after you "merge" the relevant columns into a single, nested structure:

```
val input: DataFrame = Seq(
  (1, "JAMES", "SMITH"),
  (2, "MARY", "BROWN"),
  (2, "DAVID", "WILLIAMS"),
  (1, "ROBERT", "DAVIS")
).toDF("id", "first_name", "last_name")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val result = input
  .withColumn("entity", struct($"first_name", $"last_name"))
  .groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"entity"))

result.show(false)
// +---+--------------------------------+
// |id |entities                        |
// +---+--------------------------------+
// |1  |[[JAMES,SMITH], [ROBERT,DAVIS]] |
// |2  |[[MARY,BROWN], [DAVID,WILLIAMS]]|
// +---+--------------------------------+

result.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- entities: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: haven't aware of `collect_list`and its usage, thanks.

Comment: Thank you Tzach for your answer, 
but when i try to run the code i get exception:
`AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list`

Comment: Oh, I think that means you should include `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive"` in your dependencies (in addition to `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"`), because the implementation of this function is in Spark's Hive support...

Comment: I found that I should use HiveContext instead of SQLContext to load the data. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Looks like it is, in Spark 1.6 at least (with Spark 2.0 there's no real distinction between contexts so this works with SQLContext/SparkSession too)